# Почему не удается пройти аутентификацию на сайте с моими cookies?

Tags: веб-программирование, cookie, auth, testng

У меня общий теоретический вопрос:
Почему, например, на сайте vk.com работает следующий способ(и на куче других сайтов тоже), а на другом такой метод не работает?

**Способ:**

1. Залогиниться на сайт.
2. Сохранить свои куки для этого домена.
3. Залогиниться, используя эти куки с другой программы.

**Я думал, что куки это единственный способ запомнить и идентифицировать пользователя, разве есть другие способы или я просто туплю?** 
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Скорее всего вы не тупите, но если было бы побольше информации - это могло бы помочь. Возможно cookie меняется при каждом заходе или в зависимости от еще чего-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от того, как именно реализованы механизмы идентификации и аутентификации на конкретном ресурсе. Кто-то может хранить в сессии User-Agent например, и проверять его всякий раз. Может хранить некий хэш из каких-то данных. Тогда другому браузеру Вы уже эти куки не подсунете. Вы задали очень абстрактный вопрос.

P.S. Куки далеко не единственный способ :)

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за ответы! Вообщем то я ожидал примерно таких ответов на свой вопрос, буду изучать тему подробнее, попробую сохранять User-Agent тоже для начала, а там посмотрим

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуй. Есть Session которые хранятся на сервере и так же можно идентифицировать пользователя. Почитать пример тут [php Session](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php)

Comment: Плохой ответ - ибо из вашей же ссылки: Каждому посетителю сайта присваивается уникальный идентификатор, называемый идентификатором сессии (session id). **Он хранится либо в cookie на стороне пользователя, либо передается через URL.**

Comment: Здесь автор видать хотел сказать что основная задача идентификация -  это сопроставление сессиии клиента и сессиии сервера, которая в свою очередь содержит нужные атрибуты текущего пользователя. Но это только в том случае если серверу это нужно ;)